# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

estaba realizando este script para rascar en Dateas.com y de pronto comenzó a fallar.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')] 

url = 'https://www.dateas.com/es?country=venezuela'
br.open(url)

for cedula in cedulas: #Tomo la cédula de una hoja de excel
    br.select_form(nr= 0)
    br.form['cedula'] = str(cedula)
    data = br.submit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    datos= soup.find('table',{'class':'entity-table entity-table-vertical entity-table-no-adsense'})

    count2=1
    for fila in datos.find_all('tr'): #debe copiar cada dato en una celda específica de excel
        count=2
        for c in fila.find_all('td'):
            sheet.cell(row=count, column=count2).value=c.text
            count+=1
            count2+=1
wb.save('1.xlsx')
```

Me faltaban detalles por arreglar, pero de pronto ya no encontró más la tabla y comenzó a dar error:

```
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'"
```

Ya revisé el nombre de la tabla y es ese (no ha cambiado). Por favor ¿Me pueden decir qué sucede?

Comment: Estas usando un objeto inexistente. En alguna parte de tu programa asignaste None a tu variable. Chequea que tus variables contenga algo valido.

Comment: Por ninguna parte hay nada en None como puedes ver en el script. Antes de eso solo está la apertura del libro en excel en donde itero por número de cédula para construir la lista "cedulas". Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: También debes revisar lo que te retornan las funciones que llamas.

Comment: Gracias Candid Moe, tu comentario fue útil para encontrar la falla.

Comment: El iterador 'cedula' del primer bucle for no estaba arrojando un dato correcto para ser utilizado por br.form

Comment: Eso ocurre por que estás usando un atributo de un abjeto sobre un objeto que no proviene de esa clase. Cuando le haces `find()` a `soup` ya estás generando otro objeto. Intenta aplicar las propiedades por separado al objeto generado con `BeautifulSoap()`.

Comment: Gracias gcoronel99 eso fue lo que hice desde que Candid Moe me advirtió en el comentario anterior y ya solucioné el problema.